# getting 403 forbidden error for request xml in websphere application server v8.5

Tags: rest, websphere

I am invoking a rest api(post method) from websphere application server v8.5 by passing xml and getting 403 forbidden error, it was accepting other formats(json) and returning xml parsing error.

It worked well in my local server, but getting this issue in other environment.

Please help me if anybody has came across this kind of error

Comment: make sure websphere is configured to allow access to you. were you using a jndi resource on your local? Jdbc connection? is this java?(assuming) and are you using eclipse, netbeans, intellij?

Comment: The server accepting the request if i sent in json format, for xml only getting this 403 forbidden error. In my local not using any jndi resource. It is just invoking a restful webservice, no database actions are involved here.

Comment: @satya how did u resolve it?